# When function is pushed in googletag.cmd.push will be invoked

Tags: google-ad-manager, google-publisher-tag

#### Use case

I want to check when requests for ads are being sent from GPT.

Suppose for any ad slot `s1`, ad request sent at time `t1` then I would like to print `t1-pageLoadTime` on the console.

```js
googletag.cmd.push(function () {
   // log time
});
```

But, I am not sure whether the function pushed into `googletag.cmd.push` will be called before sending an ad requests or after sending all ad request.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.cmd) googletag.cmd is just "the global command queue for asynchronous execution of GPT-related calls."

I wouldn't rely on this knowing Google Publisher Tags provide events such as :

- googletag.events.SlotRequestedEvent : "This event is fired when an ad
  has been requested for a particular slot." ([here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.events.slotrequestedevent))
- googletag.events.SlotResponseReceived : "This event is fired when an
  ad response has been received for a particular slot" ([here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.events.slotresponsereceived))

Launch a timer between slotResquestedEvent and slotResponseReceived, you will be able to get the duration between those 2 events. If you want to play whith events, take a look at [this sample page](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/samples/ad-event-listeners).

If you are interested in getting the ad load duration, I would recommend you to watch for the googletag.apiReady flag, which indicates wether the API is fully ready to be used or not ([here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.apiReady)). Combined with the slotResponseReceived, you should be able to get the data you are looking for.

Last : you might be interested in googletag.pubadsReady which indicates when the GPT service has been enabled ([here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.pubadsReady))